# How to update the data of a function without using on 'Click'

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-visualization, auto-update

I have been using this code for the data visualization of a tank, and it works very well only that I want to update it every 2 seconds, I made it call the page that contains only one tank, but it does the whole animation over and over again and it doesn't look stable, I would like to update it without having to update the whole page, maybe changing the ".on('click', function(event) {
$(this).waterTank(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 0 );" but I don't know if it is possible to do it automatically every 2 seconds. This code can be found in https://github.com/AppeonixCreativeLab/waterTank in the demo, he change the data with click, but there´s no information how to make it automatically, I hope someone can help

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>3D Water Tank</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.wrap{
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-align: center;
}
.tank{
    margin:0 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
body{
    /*background: #eee;*/
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="tank waterTankHere1"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="./waterTank.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.waterTankHere1').waterTank({
    width: 420,
    height: 360,
    color: '#8bd0ec',
    level: 83
}).on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).waterTank(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 0 );
});
```

});

The code I want to use is updating with a data from MySQL, like this way:

```
<?php  
session_start();
 //$connexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "", "grdxf");
$connexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "123456", "telemetic");
 $seleccion = "SELECT an1 FROM reportes where grd_id=".$_SESSION['GRD'].";  ";  
 $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion, $seleccion);  
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
 $dato=3*((($fila["an1"]/100)-4)/16);
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tanque de agua</title>
    <script src="Javascriptsweb/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Javascriptsweb/d3tanque3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>


.divTablata{ display: table; }
.divcedata{ background-color: beige; background: beige  }
            @font-face{
 font-family:'Digital';
 src: url('CSSweb/loopy/LOOPY_IT.ttf');
}

</style>
<div class="divTablata">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divceldata tanque1"></div></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCella"><h2 style="font-family:'Digital'; color:red;" ><?php echo $dato?> L</h2></div></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tanque1').waterTank({
            width: 100,
            height:100,
            color: '#72bddb',//color de nuestro liquido
            level:  <?php echo $dato?>,
            tamano:3// tamaño tanque
    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may find every 2s is a little too often because of the animating time. Would a slightly slower rate of change be acceptable? Also, do you want to change each of the 3 tanks every time, or only one and if only one is it chosen randomly?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I'm using a MySQL data, I'm trying to make some type of HMI,, and I'm using just one tank, I'd edit the question

Comment: There seems to be no point in what you're doing. But, if you insist, then wrap AJAX within `setInterval`.

Comment: Just to make sure I fully understand: you want to update the water level not with a random (bounded) number as in the example, but from a number of litres which are taken every 2 seconds from a backend (mySQL) database? So you want to interrogate that every 2 seconds. (i.e. some other agent may be changing the level for example from real life readings in a tank - if so I see the point). Have I understood?

Comment: that's exactly the point, maybe 2 seconds is too short for a tank, but it still reports the measurement every time it detects a 1% change in the measurement, and I'm doing it updating in another page that contains other elements the whole page at once which makes the tank appear and disappear, in the example with random numbers the tank doesn't disappear, it just updates, I would like to do that using the mysql data, without needing to click every time or update the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make what you do to draw the tank with a new value of dato into a function. Also add a bit to it so it makes an AJAX call to get the next value of dato.

Then, once you have the initial page loaded you can set a timeout of 2 seconds and call the function again and so it goes on.

Note: I don't recommend setInterval just in case something goes wrong and takes too long. If you use setTimeout each time then you know you haven't got any other requests waiting to be serviced and you can't get in a muddle. The timeout will only be set when you've had a response. In a real life situation you'll need to think through more about what to do if the backend stops responding, or sends rubbish data.

After the initial load of the page, after 2 seconds the call is made to the same url but with a parameter dato=true The backend PHP looks to see if this is set and if it is it doesn't resend the whole page it just sends what it thinks the current value of dato is.

Because I don't have access to your database I have put in a couple of lines of code to send a random value between 0 and 100 so you can see the tank level changing. Also in the JS the L value is updated with dato, but should that be some liter sort of value rather than a %? Perhaps two values need to be sent, the % fullness and the actual volume? If so then sending them as JSON may be the answer.

Here's the altered backend code. It uses jquery's AJAX method (which does have a JSON option should you need it). For a short time this will be available on [tanktemp](https://ahweb.org.uk/tanktemp.php) so you can see it working immediately.

```
<?php
// REMOVE THE COMMENT FROM AROUND THIS NEXT 7 LINES OF PHP FOR PRODUCTION VERSION
/* 
session_start();
 //$connexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "", "grdxf");
$connexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "123456", "telemetic");
 $seleccion = "SELECT an1 FROM reportes where grd_id=".$_SESSION['GRD'].";  ";  
 $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion, $seleccion);  
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
 $dato=3*((($fila["an1"]/100)-4)/16);
*/
// REMOVE THE NEXT TWO LINES OF PHP FOR PRODUCTION VERSION -->
  $dato = 10;
  if ($_GET['dato']) { echo rand(0,100); die();}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tanque de agua</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="waterTank.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>


.divTablata{ display: table; }
.divcedata{ background-color: beige; background: beige  }
            @font-face{
 font-family:'Digital';
 src: url('CSSweb/loopy/LOOPY_IT.ttf');
}

</style>
<div class="divTablata">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divceldata tanque1"></div></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCella"><h2 style="font-family:'Digital'; color:red;" ><?php echo $dato?> L</h2></div></div>
</div>
<script>

let dato = <?php echo $dato?>;
    $(document).ready(showTank);
function showTank(){
    document.querySelector('.divTableCella h2').innerHTML = dato + ' L';
    $('.tanque1').waterTank({
            width: 100,
            height:100,
            color: '#72bddb',//color de nuestro liquido
            level:  dato,
            tamano:3// tamaño tanque
    });
    $.ajax({
    url: '?dato=true',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        dato = data;
        setTimeout(showTank, 2000);
    },
    error: function (error) { 
        alert('oh dear - please see console');
        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }
});

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My God, what a great help you have just given me, I can even improve all my other visualizations with this, I used to update the whole page in each one. Thank you so much, what a nice guy

Comment: Glad it worked out. It was an interesting visualisation, simple but effective.